# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, strip

I am trying to strip the white space from the platform.system value so I can compare it in some if/else logic. I am getting the error below. What am I missing?

**line 9, in 
print(os_name.strip())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strip'**

```
import platform

os_name = platform.system
os_name_strip = os_name.strip()

print('OS Name      :', os_name_strip)

if os_name == 'Windows':
    print('we have an OS match')
else:
    print('we do not have an OS match')
```

Comment: Typo: `os_name = platform.system()` -- you need parentheses when calling a function

Comment: Thanks @costaparas, that solved the issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
import platform
os_name = platform.system()
os_name_strip = os_name.strip()

print('OS Name      :', os_name_strip)

if os_name == 'Windows':
    print('we have an OS match')
else:
    print('we do not have an OS match')

OS Name      : Windows
we have an OS match
```

Comment: Thanks @nectarBee for including the working code and output. I updated my code and it is working great.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned the actual function `platform.system` into your `os_name` variable. To execute the function and store the output value instead, make sure to include the parenthesis:

```
os_name = platform.system()
```

Comment: This is one of those mistakes that you (hopefully) make only once.

Comment: Agreed @MarkRansom and I am not sure how I missed that. Thanks!!